# При попытке копировать файл возникает ошибка: не удалось найти указанный файл

Tags: cmd

Я буквально вчера начал разбираться с командной строкой Windows и пытаюсь скопировать все файлы из директории 1 в директорию 2, но при попытке у меня появляется вот такая ошибка:

C:\cmdTest>forfiles /s /m *.txt /c "copy c:\cmdtest1"

ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.
ОШИБКА: Не удается найти указанный файл.

Причем количество этих ошибок равно количеству файлов, которые должны быть скопированы.
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
forfiles /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c copy @file c:\cmdtest1"
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно узнать почему нужно писать именно так?

Comment: в справке всё расписано `forfiles /?`